# Check query string is present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL

```
http://www.abctest.com/?user=someVal&place=someVal
```

What I need is to check if `place` is available within the query string? I need only to check if place is there or not (not looking to get the value of place).

Comment: Did you try [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: @Tushar Thank you. No. I do not know about it. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Tushar, `indexOf` will return `>0` even if 'place' is a value of any query string key..

Comment: @Becky Currently, the question shows no efforts, add your efforts

Comment: @RayonDabre , @Tushar then how bout `indexOf` "&place" or "?place"

Comment: @Coderchu How about taking advantage of second param of `indexOf`

Comment: I'm trying to write a common function that checks if `place` is available or not. I know how to get values but I posted this thinking that there would be a easy way to find if a query string parameter available or noy. (e.g. http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html).

Comment: I hope 'contains()' will work for this.

Comment: Why not regex ? `/(place)\w+/g`

Comment: @Becky This is not a simple question that a simple `indexOf` can solve. We about talking about patterns here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.indexOf` to determine if one string contains another one, but it will return `true` if `place` substring takes place in any part of the URL.

Another approach is to use JavaScript URL object:

```
var urlObject = new URL("http://www.abctest.com/?user=someVal&place=someVal");
var query = urlObject.search.substring(1); // user=someVal&place=someVal

var hasPlaceParameter = query.split('&').some(function(x) { 
    return x.substring(0, 6) === 'place='; 
});
```

You can use ES6 `startsWith` function instead of `substring(0, 6)`.

Comment: _You can use String.prototype.indexOf to determine if one string contains another one, but it will return true if place substring takes place in any part of the URL._**???** ==> `str.indexOf('place=', str.indexOf('?'))`

Comment: @Tushar Yes, it is possible to find a hacky one `indexOf` solution, but it is pretty difficult. For example, this solution fails for url `http://example.com/?notaplace=someVal`.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
var text = "http://www.abctest.com/?user=someVal&place=someVal";
var result = text.match(/(\&|\?)place\=/);

if (result != null) {
    // Your search string is available
}
```

Comment: `http://abctest.com/?place=someVal&user=someVal`

Comment: Well, a small modification will satisfy your confusion.

Comment: Use `[?&]`, `test()`, no need of escaping `=`